# receiving undefined variable when attempting to use count(*) in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show the number of sales/buys a sales person has done. I have a search box which when I type in their name it should bring back a number . So to count total buys I am using this code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect ("****", "****","****")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("*******");

 $term = $_POST['term'];


$sql = mysql_query("select count(*) from car_orders where side='buy' and sales_id like '%$term%'");


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 echo 'owner_id: '.$row['sales_id'];
echo '<br/> side '.$row['side'];
echo '<br/><br/>';
 }
?>
```

I have tried finding out how to just get the count figure to show on the page and have failed. Please could somebody help

Comment: Your query does not include either the `sales_id` or the `side` columns, but you are attempting to fetch them

Comment: You're not fetching either sales_id or side in your query; and you don't seem to be doing anything with the count(*) you are fetching.

Comment: Please note that thwe `mysql_xx()` functions are considered obsolete. PHP is in the process of deprecating them, and the PHP manual has big red boxes on every relevent page suggesting using the alternatives (`mysqli_xx()` or the PDO library). For more info see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `ALIAS`

```
select count(*) AS totalCOUNT from car_orders where ....
```

and you can now get the value using that

```
$row['totalCOUNT']
```

but seeing on your query, neither `sales_id` nor `side` were projected. The query below is *only an assumption*

```
select `sales_id`,`side`, count(*) AS totalCOUNT
from car_orders 
where side='buy' and 
      sales_id like '%$term%'
GROUP BY `sales_id`,`side`
```

and now you can fetch all values,

```
$row['sales_id']
$row['side']
$row['totalCOUNT']
```

and that query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Please take time to read the article below how to protect from it,

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Is there anyway of seeing the total count for buy and sell?

Comment: Yh the query did work I now can see the total buys done by a specific sales person. But is it possible to see total buys and total sells?

Comment: ah you mean the grand total. where will be the record do you want to be shown?

Comment: no not necessarily a total. At present it shows sales persons name: side buy and the number of buys. I also want to add the number of sells? is it possible to append to the sql query to cater for this?

Comment: yes, but i don't know the structure of your table. :( can you post the structure, sample record, and desired output? :D

Comment: no that won't be possible. But the sell and buy are in the same column headed side. The desired output is what you just provided but it would be awesome if I could also get a count for total sells

Comment: Another day, another working SQL injection hole. This desperately needs a call to `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @user1783326 is this what you want? `select sales_id,side, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy,
  SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell
from car_orders 
where side='buy' and 
      sales_id like '%$term%'
GROUP BY sales_id,side`

Comment: Thanks for your effort. but the sell query is returning a value of 0. I think the problem lies in the "where side='buy'" how do I concatenate this with side='sell'

Comment: oops try this, `select sales_id, SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell from car_orders where side='buy' and sales_id like '%$term%' GROUP BY sales_id`

Comment: nope that didnt do it. The strange thing is in  the where side='buy' if i change this to where side='sell' I see the sells and the buy returns 0.

Comment: sorry for the query, can you remove the that condition so you arrive on this `select sales_id, SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell from car_orders where sales_id like '%$term%' GROUP BY sales_id`

Comment: thanks John I really appreciate that. Thanks really for persevering with me.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're only selecting the `COUNT(*)` column and nothing else.
2. You're not using `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, so it's not an associative array.
3. The `mysql_` functions are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.